# Reading xml from Dataframe column in scala, How to Read non mandatory xml element?

Tags: xml-parsing, scala-xml

I have a requirement where I need to process a column in a dataframe containing an XML. I am trying to convert the XML column from dataframe into multiple individual columns based on the tags.

MyDataframe look like this -
+---------+--------------------+
|id|            xmldata|
+---------+--------------------+
|    18284|<?xml version="1....|
|    18307|<?xml version="1....|
|    18297|<?xml version="1....|
|    18282|<?xml version="1....|
|    18304|<?xml version="1....|
+---------+--------------------+

xml looks like this-
``
(18284,"123277311<Customers test="a">100"),
(18307,"176344<Customers test="b">200"),
(18297,"299366<Customers test="c">300")

val xmlrdd = df.select("xmldata").map(a => a.getString(0)).rdd
val xmldf = new XmlReader().xmlRdd(spark.sqlContext, xmlrdd).select($"details.Customers._test".as("cust_test"),$"details.Customers._VALUE".as("cust_val"),$"details.addr.line1".as("Addrl1"),$"details.addr.line2".as("Addrl2"),$"details.addr.line3".as("Addrl3"))
xmldf.show

``

if I try to select element, which is expected but not present in any of the xml record. How to Handle xml non mandatory xml elements  ??
I want NULL values for xml elements which are not present in xml while parsing.